# How Can I Disable Year Selection in WPF Calendar

Tags: c#, wpf

- I want to make a calendar like Google's Calendar to Show all days of the year in one screen.

  - I will use 12 `Calendar` instances.
- I want To disable the year selection from the header of the WPF `Calendar` to look like a label, rather than a clickable button.

[image: WPF Calendar]

Comment: Are you looking for a XAML-only solution, or is init-time C# okay?

Comment: Also, exactly what version of WPF and .NET are you using?

Comment: Is this meant to be a read-only calendar, or is it interactable and are users meant to be able to select a date (or dates)?  We need more details about what you're actually trying to do. What about its different display modes (decades, years, months, quarters, etc)? Also, the WPF Calendar has keyboard navigation support (for accessibility) so simply disabling the header elements won't stop users from being able to interact with it.

Comment: In WPF i would encourage you to build your own calendar, it should be fairly easy but you would benefit from learning also this way you could build entire view and model to your needs and reuse it.

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz Building _any_ calendar control is far, far, far from "fairly easy" - I'll say it's probably one of the most complicated controls in any widget-library. And that's long before you have to deal with localization issues and supporting different calendar systems.

Comment: Why? 
All you need is extracting each month, could be hardcoded, than by month extract the number of days. All is left is binding both lists to approperiate views. 
Only difficulty i can think of seems to be that February varies in (day count), therefor you would have to decide on the number of days you want to view (could be extracted by current or static year).

So im seriously asking, as im not a pro, and i could learn something :)

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz Sorry, but your (frankly) _naive optimism_ in your comment made me chuckle because the grim reality is that dates and times are amongst the hardest things to deal with in computer code, and it's why no-one should ever write their own date/time library, much less a calendar control. For example, https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time - there are **far**, _far_ [more](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) cases to consider than just February-being-weird.

Comment: Most of those issues rely on time issues, if you operate around DateTime, and CurrentCulture, than i actually don't belive it would be that hard. Offcourse there is also a question is if author only needs dd, mm and yyyy, and is he talking of some generic year (which does not exists) or current year, but without seeing it.  Monday-Sunday placement also shouldn't be that hard. But i agree if we throe in time, it gets a lot more complicated as it's part of DatePickers ill give you that.

Comment: Ok, just read entire article, i still stand that if he wants only date where only days, months and year count that should be fairly easy, but he has to think of implementing information about time zone from current culture. Damn i also agree that it highly depends on what is data needed for. I agree i was naive, with my thinking of hes needs it should be quite fast to do, but anything beyond that is fair to assume would be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by setting "IsHitTestVisible" = false to "PART_HeaderButton" in the Control Template.
this is the Control template Which i used

[Calendar Control Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: `IsHitTestVisible` doesn't disable keyboard navigation, btw.

Comment: i limited the date range for each month i displayed so, keyboard navigation doesn't exceed this range.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the [DisplayDateStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydatestart?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and the [DisplayDateEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaydateend?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties of [The Calender Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/calendar?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

For example in XAML, you could do:

```
<Calendar DisplayDateStart="1/1/2022" DisplayDateEnd="31/12/2022"/>
```

Or in code-behind:

```
Calendar cal = new Calendar();
cal.DisplayDateStart = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);
cal.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2022, 12, 31);
```

Limitations: This only restricts the display range, as pointed out int the comment.

Comment: This only restricts the _displayed_ range, not the selectable range.

Comment: I want to disable the Calendar header with its all info to be Shown Only.

Comment: @PeterBoshra Are you saying you want the calendar to be `ReadOnly` **and** only show dates in the current year? Your original post only mentioned restricting year selection (implying you only want dates in the current year to be selectable, you didn't say anything about it being read-only).

Comment: @Dai Not All Calendar , Only The Header Be Read only

Comment: @PeterBoshra Why, though? Doing that won't stop users from being able to select dates from different years and months (due to keyboard navigation, or via data-binding, etc). _You need to think more thoroughly_ about how you want WPF's calendar control to behave, not just how it looks.

Comment: @Dai I want to make a calendar like Google's Calendar to Show all days of the year in one screen

Comment: @PeterBoshra That's not possible. The WPF calendar does not support showing 365 days at once. The `CalendarMode.Year` mode makes it show 12 months which then drill-down to month-views, and that's not what you're describing. [This is what `CalendarMode.Year` looks like](https://wpf-tutorial.com/Images/ArticleImages/1/misc-controls/calendar_display_year.png)

Comment: i will use 12 calendars

Comment: @PeterBoshra That will work - but why didn't you mention that in your original post? That's a very important detail.

Comment: i mentioned the problem directly to not wasting time in reading

Comment: @PeterBoshra A single sentence that _greatly clarifies your intention_ is "not wasting time" - it's a very important detail.